Return True/False of EXISTS Postgres query not being recognized by IF statement

def track_exists():
      conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=***)
      cur = conn.cursor()
      sqltest = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMERS  WHERE CUSTOMERS.PHONE = '608-888-8888')"
      cur.execute(sqltest)
      result = cur.fetchall()
      if result == [(True,)]:
            print("working")
            dosomething()
      elif result == "":
            print("not working")

When running this function in VS CODE the output returns exactly, [(True,)] to the screen . My if statement does not recognize this as being true and returns my "not working" statement. No matter what way I've tried different versions of true, IE "True:" , "(True)," "True," etc...
      phonestring = phone_str
      print (phonestring)
      conn = psycopg.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=***)
      cur = conn.cursor()
      sqltest = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMERS  WHERE CUSTOMERS.PHONE = (%s))"
      sqldata = (phonestring)
      cur.execute(sqltest,sqldata)
      result = cur.fetchone()
      if result == [(True,)][0]: 
            print("Customer Exists")
      elif result == [(False,)][0]:
            print("New customer")


Something is fishy. When I try a similar snippet, it works just fine. It seems unlikely that the elif result=="" branch would be taken if resultactually prints as [(True,)].  You say that there is output under VS Code, but there is nothing in your code that produces any output (except fixed texts). Please provide a reproduceable example.

(Besides that, you usually don’t want to do equality comparisons on booleans; you want to dig them out and use them directly, like if result[0][0]: doSomething() .)


Since you are going to only return a single result I would use fetchone(). 2) I cannot replicate as shown. 3) Not sure how you are getting to result == "": as EXISTS will return either True or False, not an empty string, per docs EXISTS: If it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is “true”; if the subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is “false”.


@TurePålsson This is an example, in my actual code the EXISTS query will take a variable ( %s) in place of the fixed string i am using for testing purposes. However the EXISTS statement on its own produces the output [(True,])/[(False,)].

If you are give us an example not actual code, then you need to test the example and describe what really happens with it.  I don't see how this example could possibly "returns exactly, [(True,)] to the screen".  Like the others, I can't reproduce any issue.

I've added the real code, not sure how its very different really the fixed string I had in place as an example is simply going to be a variable instead.  I just need to figure out how to make the variable work with my EXISTS statement, that's why I was testing with a fixed string.


Given this result = cur.fetchone() this if result == [(True,)][0]:  should be simplified to if result == (True,): as fetchone() only returns a single result so there is no list involved. 2) If you are getting [(True,)] in the VS Code output then that code is using fetchall(). Indicates to me you are working on two different versions of the code.


Thank you very much @TurePålsson for your insight! I was able to get the code working by using the tuple "if result == [(True,)][0]:" However I still do not know exactly what this code is doing and why I need to specify a 0 or anything else for the second value.

There is something you are not showing us as [(True,)] == [(True,)] is True and [(True,)][0] is (True,). This means result is (True,), which means you are either using cur.fetchone() or iterating over the output of fetchall() to get the the row tuples in the the result set.

I've added the real code, not sure how its very different really the fixed string I had in place as an example is simply going to be a variable instead. I just need to figure out how to make the variable work with my EXISTS statement, that's why I was testing with a fixed string.

Adam Klaver’s comment was spot on — the important difference is that you are calling fetchone, not fetchall. Make sure you understand what he says about [(True,)][0] being the same as just (True,). And you should still probably be doing if result[0]: print(...)
